# How to pass "complex" multiple parts params as SOAP Request to Mule SOAP Client

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, anypoint-studio

I would like to know how pass complex params to Mule SOAP Client, in a simple form, similar to Web Service Consumer component. I can't to use component because the Web Service has several parts and it does not work with n parts.

I tried to do like this: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/consuming-web-services-with-cxf but does not clear how to make input complex params.

I am using Mule CE 3.7.

In SoapUI, the envelop request is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.abcde.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:obterCliente>
         <user>name.surname</user>
         <password>xxxxx</password>
         <encryption>0</encryption>
         <parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <codigoCli>1</codigoCli>
         </parameters>
      </ser:obterCliente>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any example about how to pass complex params to SOAP in Mule?

Comment: And where is the complexity ? I only see a soap request with a custom body. Can you give more details ?

Comment: "Complex" like "Multi Parts". The Web Service Consumer https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/web-service-consumer does not work with multi parts. Throw a message: "Operation Messages With More then 1 Part Are Not Supported". I am finding a simple solution/example similar this component for multiple parts.

Comment: Hi @Muka, the complex params is part of your XSD which defines the definition of XML schema or structure of you XML which is embedded to the WSDL. You can check the WSDL of you SOAP provider by doing http://<ws endpoint>?wsdl